# how shall I define sequences in my project (which uses hibernate) in a way that the project works with both Oracle and Mysql.

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, sequence

We have a java project that uses Hibernate as the OR Mapper. We need the project to work with both Oracle and Mysql. because some customers don't want to install Oracle. we have added @sequenceGenerator annotation on entities to have sequence. but the project can not connect to Mysql DBMS with these annotations. Is there any way that we can have sequences in both mysql and Oracle mode, without any changes?

Comment: Sequences in Oracle ~= Auto-Increments in MySQL; can't it addressed in DB migration/creation scripts?

Comment: thanks SparKot, but i dont have problem with my data, I want my code to remain unchanged while i can execute it with both Oracle and MySQL with sequences (without changing all @sequenceGenerator annotations to auto-increement and vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most portable way is to use [TableGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html). It is portable because no database provider specific constructs are used. Last generated value is stored to the database table, and value is retrieved and incremented via SQL queries.

Usage is also covered in Hibernate [documentation.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)

Comment: Home-grown Sequences (i.e. not done natively *in* the database) are slow and not scalable. If Hibernate can't even cope with different (generic) ways to generate an artificial primary key then it's even worse than I thought. What's the use of an abstraction layer if it doesn't abstract the way keys are generated? It should be able to use sequences for Oracle (and Postgres, DB2, Firebird, SQL,...) and auto_increment for MySQL (or identity for SQL Server).

Comment: Thanks Mikko, You mean that by using TableGenerator instead of @sequenceGenerator, my code will work with both Oracle and MySQL properly and generates sequences in both of them?

Comment: @MikkoMaunu in documentation that you had introduced, in description of GenerationType.Table, it says: "the hi/lo algorithm generates identifiers that are unique only for a particular database". does hi/lo algorithm have this property in common or only in GenerationType.Table? because i want to have clustering database in future, i want to be sure that tableGenerator wont make me any difficulties then. thanks

Comment: @MikkoMaunu I have another question: can you please introduce me a reference that is compared the GenerationType.TABLE and GenerationType.SEQUENCE? I need to know which one is better according to performance issues.

Comment: Thank you @MikkoMaunu. your answer was really helpful and we are using it now in our project :)

Answer (score 0):

in accordance to my knowledge it is not possible because

MySQL support **AUTO_INCREMENT** and Oracle support **SEQUENCE**

and there are many other factors to consider like data types and indexes

As Oracle is an **ORDBMS** where as mysql is **DBMS** it is lack of many features present in MySQL

## SOLUTION

i think we can do this with separate databases for each of them

[ As we have many free tools to convert the data from Oracle to MySQL we can use them. Even some of them are not free but we can covert the structure usnig them [link1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/mysql-093223.html) [link2]](http://dbconvert.com/convert-oracle-to-mysql-pro.php)

database migration needs a full understanding of the data types,indexes,column and table options,etc of both source and destination databases

or

you can use PostgreSQl which also supports **SEQUENCES** and it is also a GPL

Comment: Java is not my area; however I used [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) to migrate from MySQL to Oracle.

Comment: PostgreSQL is **not** GPL, it's a BSD license which is much more liberal (some same *really* free) license.

Comment: as I said in previous comments, my problem is not with data migration, I already have 2 separate databases, but as I have implemented the sequence in oracle by means of hibernate annotations (and not in DB), i have problems with this project and sequence annotations when i want to execute it with MySQL.

Comment: dear vidyadhar, I have chosen MySQL because it is easy to use and light enough for using in small projects, if you can recommend a light DB other than MySQL that supports SEQUENCE exactly like the Oracle, it will also help. thanks ;)

Comment: hi mana mandegar it is better for you to use postgresql ( support sequences )